# How did Rumpelstiltskin find Henry?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

I am currently at the start of the second season of Once Upon a Time, so if my question will be answered later simply let me know that it will with no spoilers please.

How did Rumpelstiltskin find Henry to bring him to Regina? While the curse was active nobody could leave Storybrook except Emma, Henry and Pinnochio who were not affected by the curse. How could Rumpelstiltskin find a specific boy to bring to Regina for her to adopt?
Given that Rumpelstiltskin still remembers during the curse but is afraid to leave in the initial stages that curse was broken (fearing that he will lose his memories) that means the effects of leaving Storybrook take place on him as well. So how did he find Henry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be explained during season 3.

Spoilers from [Season 3, Episode 9](http://onceuponatimeabc.wikia.com/wiki/Save_Henry):

> Mr Gold doesn't procure the baby, only the information of it. It is Regina who leaves Storybrooke (she is able to as it is her curse) to meet with the adoption agency. It is not clear how Mr Gold got the information, but it is entirely possible that he did so without leaving town.

Comment: I don't want any spoilers. Thanks for putting the proper tags so I could not view it immediately :D

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that he could indeed leave the area to conduct some business and then return later, but if one attempt to LEAVE, as in not intending or wanting to go back when you step over the town line, then the curse struck you in the face?

Comment: From what I see, nobody could leave except reggina

Comment: downvoting because iirc they couldn't leave